# What does it mean for a Setter to be index preserving?

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

I'm trying to gain some intuition about Setters in `lens`. It's easy to run into an [IndexedSetter](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.14/docs/src/Control.Lens.Type.html#IndexedSetter) which requires rather intimidating `Conjoined` class:

```
class
  ( Choice p, Corepresentable p, Comonad (Corep p), Traversable (Corep p)
  , Strong p, Representable p, Monad (Rep p), MonadFix (Rep p), Distributive (Rep p)
  , Costrong p, ArrowLoop p, ArrowApply p, ArrowChoice p, Closed p
  ) => Conjoined p where
```

But for functions, it's quite trivial:

```
class Conjoined p => Indexable i p where
  -- | Build a function from an 'indexed' function.
  indexed :: p a b -> i -> a -> b

instance Indexable i (->) where
  indexed = const
```

It seems that `i` is not constrained in any way other than being an argument after `p a b`.

What makes it an "index" and should I care about it when working with `Setter`s?

Answer (score 1):

There's two questions here. The first one: what is "index preserving", there is a hint in other docs:

> `f . g` (and `f .> g`) gives you the index of `g` unless `g` is index-preserving, like a `Prism`, `Iso` or `Equality`, in which case it'll pass through the index of `f`.

The other question: `i` is constrained in other `Indexable` instance:

```
instance i ~ j => Indexable i (Indexed j)
```

where

```
-- | A function with access to a index. ...
newtype Indexed i a b = Indexed { runIndexed :: i -> a -> b }
```

Shortly, this is an encoding trick to make indexed and non-indexed optics to compose. We stay polymorphic in `Profunctor`, and instantiate it with  `(->)` or `Indexed i` much later.